# BadMethodCallException Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 tables which are polls, poll_questions and poll_choices. Their relation is polls has many poll_questions and poll_questions has many poll_choices. I am trying to insert but i get an error BadMethodCallException for poll_choices().

Poll Model :

```
public function poll_questions() {
    return $this->hasMany(PollQuestion::class);
}
```

Poll Question Model :

```
public function polls() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Poll::class, 'poll_id');
}

public function poll_choices() {
    return $this->hasMany(PollChoice::class);
}
```

Poll Choices Model :

```
public function poll_questions() {
    return $this->belongsTo(PollQuestion::class, 'poll_question_id');
}
```

Here is my controller :

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $rules = [
        'title'     => 'required',
        'questions' => 'required|poll_questions',
    ];

    $this->validate($request, $rules);


    $newPoll = Poll::create(request()->all());
    $questions = $request->input('questions');
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($questions); $i++) {
        $poll_question = new PollQuestion();
        $poll_question->input_type = $questions[$i]["input_type"];
        $poll_question->question = $questions[$i]["question"];

        $newPoll->poll_questions()->save($poll_question);

        if ($questions[$i]["input_type"] === '0') {
            for ($j = 0; $j < count($questions[$i]["choices"]); $j++) {
                $poll_choices = new PollChoice();
                $poll_choices->choice = $questions[$i]["choices"][$j];
                $newPoll->poll_questions()->poll_choices()->save($poll_choices);
            }
        }
    }

    return $this->showOne($newPoll);
}
```

I get an error in this line : `$newPoll->poll_questions()->poll_choices()->save($poll_choices);`

Also, i tried : `$newPoll->poll_questions->poll_choices()->save($poll_choices);`

I can add poll and poll_question perfect. But when i try to add poll choice, it gives an error. I can not access poll_questions' poll_choices method.

How can i fix this problem ?

Laravel 5.4

***Full Error Log :***

> BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::poll_choices()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already saved the poll question, and associated it with the poll, when you do this:

```
$newPoll->poll_questions()->save($poll_question);
```

So all that remains is to save the choices to the question, you don't need to involve the parent poll any more.  So in your question loop, use this instead of what you have:

```
$poll_question->poll_choices()->save($poll_choices);
```